# Quick deployment of an app after build without running

Tags: iphone, xcode

Via Xcode is there a quick way to deploy an app you've just compiled to an attached iPhone without actually launching it on the phone?

My scenario is that I've tested it out my app just fine in the simulator, now I just want to deploy it to my provisioned iPhone, grab the device and go without running it then and there. Sure, I can just hit build & run after I've set the target settings to release & device, but that attempts to initiate a GDB session and it even complains if my phone is in screen lock mode.

Not a huge problem of course, and I'm not really asking how to deploy the same app to a lot of other testers who weren't involved in the development and aren't running Xcode, just if I might have missed some kind of 'build & deploy' option that doesn't attempt to run the app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could always build and archive, save it somewhere and copy it via iTunes... I doubt it is much faster or any more convenient. I'll use Build'n'Run all the time and stop with stop button or home button. At least you make sure that it actually runs and starts on the device. :-)

Comment: build and archive is a great way to share IPA's with clients and testers

Comment: I'm not at the point where I'm sharing my work with others yet, so it looks like I'll have to just live with hitting the home button. +1 though for the reminder that at least it's a reminder that the app works.