# What are all the methods to deploy an iPhone application?

Tags: iphone, deployment

Can anyone enlist the all deployment methods along with some description and requirements?
I know there are methods to use iTune and methods to avoid iTunes, you can use App Store or not, etc.

Comment: Have you done any research? What are you trying to do? iTunes and App Store are your only significant option if you're looking to make a mass-distributed app.

Comment: as pointed out below: no, there are at least 4 different deployment options. And enterprise and ad-hoc over safari aint' very common knowledge, so I think the question makes a lot of sense

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Four Options Plus the obvious webapp choice:

1. **Developer Deploy**: Deploy from XCode using the build and run function to a connected device. The provisioning profiles is only valid for a max of three months, and it's required to have the device connected to the computer to run. Really, only for debugging.
2. **Ad-Hoc Deploy**: Signed with a Ad-Hoc Distribution Certificate for up to 100 pre registered devices. Requires the UDID of all those devices perfor packaging. Can be deployed using either itunes on the device users computer of via a link that points to the right safari file. Check this blog for more info about ad-hoc install per Mobile Safari [Parade of Raind](http://www.paradeofrain.com/2010/11/taking-the-pain-out-of-ad-hoc-testing/)
3. **Appstore**: Well, yeah. It's kinda, you know. Right.
4. **Enterprise Appstore**: Grab a Enterprise Certificate by apple, costs 300$, and you can do the same you can do with ad-hoc Deploys, but without preregistering the devices. However, you're only allowed to use this method for In-house (inside the company) deployments!

Comment: Thanks, this is what I needed, a some sort of a mini-digest

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

[PDF] http://manuals.info.apple.com/en_US/Enterprise_Deployment_Guide.pdf
http://www.airplaysdk.com/docs.php?url=/main/programmertools/mkbfilesettings/deploymentoptions.html
[Quick deployment of an app after build without running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3168157/quick-deployment-of-an-app-after-build-without-running)